# How do I customize row and column for 'react-table' library?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

This is the example table that I want to do

[image]

From the 'Yellow' highlight (row & column) color. I need to customize that data. And another data in the table work as 'react-table' do.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: https://react-table.js.org/#/story/cell-renderers-custom-components

Answer (score 1):

Using props. It's a simple.

For example:

```
columns: [ {
            Header: "data",
            accessor: "data",
            headerClassName: 'header_cell',
            className: 'table_cell'
        },{
            Header: {your data},
            accessor: {your data},
            headerClassName: 'header_cell'
        }]
```

and then use css.